# Override default CSS for table

Tags: html, css, overriding

I am making a table on a webpage inside Zetaboards forum software. When I am trying to create alternating background color for each row, the forum's default CSS intervenes.

My HTML:

```
<table class="stats">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My CSS:

```
table.stats tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #333;
}
table.stats tbody tr {
  background-color: #232;
}
```

The above works just as I want it to in cssdeck.com. However, when I move it on my forum webpage, the forums "td" css takes over.

Forum CSS:

```
td {
  background-image: ...;
  background-color: ...; 
  background-position: ...;
  ...
}
```

How do I override the forum's default CSS?
I have tried adding !important, but it didn't work. I also tried to add a class for each "tr" and add tr.class in my css. That also didn't work.

I do have control over my forum's theme CSS. But I can't change it, since that "td" style is widely used across the forum design. I don't want to add a class to each td in my HTML either...

I appreciate any help I can get, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table cells are contained within table rows. When you apply background color to both rows and cells (as is the case with the above example) the cell background color will cover the rows' background color.

Workaround: add this rule to *undo* the forum's styles applied on table cells:

```
table.stats td {
    background: transparent none;
}
```

And apply background color on rows (i.e. no change in your original example):

```
table.stats tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #333;
}
table.stats tbody tr {
    background-color: #232;
}
```

Comment: your code will disturb the css of whole website.user wants to change css for  only particular table.

Comment: In this case changing to `table.stats td` should be sufficient.

Comment: OMG! that worked! thank you thank you! now only the border is showing from the default css. But, I think that is ok, I will settle with this! Thank you!

Comment: You can undo (override) those styles in your CSS. PS: do not forget to accept the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

1.)you have to add td after tr in your css

Try this:

```
 <style>
     table.stats tbody tr td:nth-child(even) { 
      background-color: #333 !important ;
    } 
    table.stats tbody tr td{ 
      background-color: #232 !important ;
    } 
</style>
```

Comment: That partially worked..but the default CSS still shows up a bit, here's a screenshot: http://prntscr.com/3rprky  And as you can see, the rows under "rank" isn't alternated now..but I added that using "table.stats tbody tr::before"

Comment: updated my answer with !important...have you used this updated code ?@Straticon

Comment: Yes, I added !important behind...and still the same thing as that screenshot

Comment: OP is trying to add background color to alternate rows. Your CSS adds background color to alternate cells.

Comment: can you please send me website link ..?

Comment: Salman's solution worked for me, it's only showing the default border now. Which is ok I suppose. Thank you for your help, really appreciate it! @Mr7-itsurdeveloper