# How to override default css of table

Tags: html, css

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158038/override-default-css-for-table) question is already on stackoverflow. But the solutions are not working for me. Actually I'm working on an Angular project. I want to align `Mode of comparison` and the corresponding `Dropdown` in the middle with respect to each other. Here is the widget that I'm creating. I've clearly marked that part in the image:

[image]

Here is my HTML:
Note: `pt-label`, `dls-combobox` and `dls-option` are my custom made angular components.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="my-row">
      <td class="first-col1">
        <div class="comparing-switch1">
          <pt-label>Mode of comparison&nbsp;</pt-label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="second-col1">
        <div class="comparing-label1">
          <dls-combobox placeholder="Time average">
            <dls-option>
              <pt-label>Time average</pt-label>
            </dls-option>
          </dls-combobox>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and here is my CSS:

```
.my-row {
    background: cornflowerblue;
}

.first-col1 {
    background: magenta;
    width: 50% !important;
}

.second-col1 {
    width: 100%;
    background: blueviolet;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

table.stats tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    vertical-align: middle !important;
}

table.stats tbody tr {
    vertical-align: middle !important
}
```

Even If I try to set it through `margin` and `padding` then both of them gets shifted even when the class names are different. One more thing I noticed. When I inspect the element `table`. When I remove `vertical-align: baseline` from these two places (as marked in the picture below) the my problem is solved:

[image]

What is wrong with my code. Please correct me.

Answer (score 0):

Here `vertical-align: baseline` property is applied to the table. `vertical-align: middle !important` is applied for *tr* element.
since table has that property tr itself aligned in baseline. try adding `vertical-align: middle` for the table